# Does a usb-c to hdmi cable actually exist?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

So my macbook pro has a usb-c  cable. I want to connect it to my tv using hdmi.

I've come across this [product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/WARRKY-Thunderbolt-Braided-Compatible-More-1-8m-4K-30Hz/dp/B08VWGSQ1D/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?adgrpid=102601119246&dchild=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw4v2EBhCtARIsACan3nw5CK0lNZxxr3eoJ5baNZXoPeVVPsXb8I9INOVB-qxb4OCv-bPOOMUaAgJnEALw_wcB&hvadid=446085903029&hvdev=c&hvlocint=9045628&hvlocphy=1006567&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=8510656436972820064&hvtargid=kwd-322941375538&hydadcr=4398_1795150&keywords=mac+usb+c+to+hdmi&qid=1621125364&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyN0tTUlZZVzVOVldNJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjc5MzAxMktKWjk2WFJZVkdKWiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMTY3OTUwRDVUR0VMVTJRNFFaJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==)

However, I'm not sure if it's a punk. It's my understanding that I need an intermediate adaptor to connect to it to my tv. Whereas this product claims to directly connect my macbook pro to the TV. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes that’s real and it will work for MacBooks with usb c ports. What leads you to believe you need an intermediate adapter?

Comment: What is a punk in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MacBook Pro models with USB type C ports offer USB, Thunderbolt 3 and DisplayPort functionality through these ports.

The cable is not a direct connection. The USB Type C jack on the MacBook Pro operates in Alt mode to provide DisplayPort output. The cable has a builtin adaptor to convert from DisplayPort to HDMI.

An adaptor has a USB Type C plug on one end and a HDMI jack on the other end. You have to use a HDMI cable with plugs on both ends to reach the monitor.

What you have is a cable (with built in adapter). This cable has a USB Type C plug on one end and a HDMI plug on the other end. You can plug this cable into the monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have one (not that make specifically but another HDMI to USB-C) and it works fine with my MacBook. There’s no need for any other components along the way.